# Should I edit long blocks of code and break them into visible sections or just let them be in a scrollable box?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I have seen a question with a very long piece of code including multiple classes.

```
---- File A ----
class A {

}
---- File B ----
class B {

}
---- File C ----
class C {

}
---- File D ----
class D {

}
/* etc



















*/
class ActuallyInteresting {
}
```

This then appears in a vertically scrollable block.

It seems hard to read. In some cases I understand the content in the scrollable box, but in other I would like to split it into separate blocks, even if the post is much longer.

My question is.

What is the right approach; if any? Shouldn't that kind of questions be splitted into multiple blocks of code, or is it up to the person asking the question?

[Here is an example of why I ask.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507139/polymorphism-java-q-from-a-test)

The tester class that is something important for the question appears hidden after all the scrolled test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer smaller separate code blocks than one large block.

Remember that for me it is the first time I see that code, I have to browse over it to be able to answer the question.

One large block is easier if it is expected that I am going to compile/run it to provide an answer. 
On the downside: larger blocks quickly become a wall-of-code that not many people want to comprehend.

Multiple blocks (with a non-code block header) are easier if the question/answer is more about structure/concepts or if the code would go in different files.

Also note: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which states: *Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem*

For that example question I would personally edit it like this: *(maybe even try to reduce it to only the relevant `equals` implementation but I'm not a java dev so I can't provide that)*

#### Classes

```
public class A 
{ 
 protected int _i; 

 public A(int i) 
 { 
 _i = i; 
 } 
} 

public class B extends A 
{ 
 public B(int i) 
 { 
 super(i+1); 
 } 
} 

public class C extends B 
{ 
 public C(int i) 
 { 
 super(i); 
 } 

 public boolean equals (Object other) 
 { 
 return ((other!=null) && 
 (other instanceof C) && 
 (_i==((C) other)._i)); 
 } 
} 

public class D extends B 
{ 
 public D(int i) 
 { 
 super(i+1); 
 } 

 public boolean equals (D other) 
 { 
 return ((other!=null) && 
 (_i==((D) other)._i)); 
 } 
}
```

#### Tester

```
public class tester {
    public static void main (String [] args) { 
         A a = new A(1); 
         B b = new B(1); 
         C c = new C(1); 
         D d = new D(1); 
         B b1 = new D(1); 
         Object c1 = new C(1); 
         Object d1 = new D(1); 
    System.out.println (d1.equals(d)); 

    } 
}
```

Why is the printed result false?

Answer (score 3):

IMO , there is no need to break [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507139/polymorphism-java-q-from-a-test) code into blocks because code is not too long.

If you think so then you can break them by java class name.

A.java

```
class A {

}
```

B.java

```
class B {

}
```

This approach makes very easy to read the question. This always good when you break the java code like this when code is long then of course it will easy to figure out the problem and understand.